# why copy constructor is called when passing temporary by const reference?

Tags: c++, gcc, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor

I am passing an unnamed temporary object to a function defined with const ref parameter. The copy ctor of the class is private, and I get a compilation error. I don't understand why a copy constructor is called in this situation.

```
class A {
public:
  A(int i) {}
private:
  A(const A&) {}
};

void f(const A& a)
{
}

int main()
{
  f(A(1)); // <-- error here: 'A::A(const A&)' is private
}
```

As expected, when I change the main to:

```
A a(1);
f(a);
```

it works.

EDIT: the compiler is gcc 4.1.2

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: VC++9 is happy to compile the first variant.

Comment: @sharptooth: gcc, I'll update

Comment: @davka: gcc? which version? gcc-4.3.4 compiles it fine: http://www.ideone.com/7sZ17

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected const reference behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249147/unexpected-const-reference-behavior)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Constructor Needed with temp object.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826934/copy-constructor-needed-with-temp-object)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find the answer to your question in [Copy Constructor Needed with temp object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826934/copy-constructor-needed-with-temp-object) or go directly to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#cxx%5Frvalbind

> The C++ Standard says that a temporary
>   object should be created in this
>   context and its contents filled with a
>   copy of the object we are trying to
>   bind to the reference; it also says
>   that the temporary copy can be elided,
>   but the semantic constraints (eg.
>   accessibility) of the copy constructor
>   still have to be checked.
>
> For further information, you can
>   consult the following paragraphs of
>   the C++ standard: [dcl.init.ref]/5,
>   bullet 2, sub-bullet 1, and
>   [class.temporary]/2.
>
> Starting with GCC 4.3.0, GCC no longer
>   gives an error for this case. This
>   change is based on the intent of the
>   C++ language committee. As of
>   2010-05-28, the final proposed draft
>   of the C++0x standard permits this
>   code without error.

Answer (score 24):

The expression `A(1)` is an *rvalue* 5.2.3 [expr.type.conv].

In initializing a `const` reference (the function argument) with an expression that is an *rvalue* the compiler *may* create a temporary and copy the value of that expression to the temporary and bind that reference to that temporary. 8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref] / 5.

> [...] The constructor that would be used to make the copy shall be callable whether or not the copy is actually done.

Note that this behaviour is due to change in the next version of C++. In the new standard a `const` reference initialized from a class *prvalue* must be bound directly to the reference object; no temporary is permitted to be created in this case and a copy constructor is not used or required.

Comment: thanks. your last paragraph explains why this does not happen in the newer version of gcc as per @Nawaz comment, correct?

Comment: @davka: I believe that that is the reason, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Because a(1) calls the constructor A(int i) and then A(const A&) is called in the call to void f(const A&).

Make the A(int i) constructor  explicit and you should not face this error.

Edit: I think i misunderstood the question. I might delete this.

Comment: **From the C++ standard §3.2 paragraph 2:**
A copy constructor is used even if the
call is actually elided by the
implementation.

Comment: The copy constructor should conceptually not be called here, that's the point of the question. Passing by reference implies no creation of a new object, hence no copy.

Comment: Why the down-vote? It is actually correct, according to the standard.

Comment: @dalle:The piece you quote is for RVO-like cases, not for the situation in the question.

Comment: @sharptooth: Even though the copy constructor isn't called, it is still *used*.

Comment: @dalle:No, it is not used - the object is passed by reference, not by value. It would be used if the object was passed by value only, then perhaps RVO-like copy elision could take place and the piece you quote would kick in.

Comment: @sharptooth: My first reference to the C++ standard was incorrect, but see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#391

Comment: @dalle: I see now, in that cse it can be *used* and even *called*, but I wouldn't ever expect such  behavior.