# Calling constructor in return statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class test{

public:

    int data;
    test(const test& ){cout<<"INSIDE COPY CON "<<endl;}
    test(int val = 0) : data(val){ cout<<"INSIDE CON "<<endl; }

    test testfun(const test& obj)
    {
        cout<<"data : "<<data<<endl;
        //test test3(this->data + obj.data);
        //cout<<"test3 :"<<test3.data<<endl;
        //return test3;   //This will work only if return type is changed to const ref
        return test(data + obj.data); 


    }
};

int main()
{

    test testO1(1);
    test testO2(2);
    test testO3 = testO1.testfun(testO2);

    cout<<testO3.data<<endl;


    getchar();


}
```

OUTPUT:

```
INSIDE CON

INSIDE CON

data : 1

INSIDE CON

3
```

What happens when constructor is called in return statement? Since i am able to return by value and it works i think its not a temporary location. OR is it creating the object as a temporary and using copy constructor to copy the values , inthat case why is the print inside the copy constructor not getting printed.

Comment: More on [NRVO](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) and [copy elision](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html) in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask a penetrating question.

It is up to the compiler and the associated toolchain to decide what to do, but the basic pattern is as follows.  Before calling `testfun()`, the caller [`main()`, in your example] reserves space for `test03` on the stack.  It then passes the address of `test03` to `testfun()`.

The function `testfun()` must somehow put a `test` object at the address the caller has supplied.  If the function has only one return statement, *it is free to use the storage provided by the caller* to build the return value.  It need not use its own storage.  It can use `main()`'s.

Now, this strategy does not always work.  It typically fails when a function like `testfun()` has two, distinct return statements, one or both of which return not a temporary but a named object.  In that case, the compiler is forced to do an otherwise unnecessary copy-on-return.  However, the more usual case resembles yours, in which `testfun()` just builds the return value directly in the spot in which `main()` wants it.  In this case, no actual copy occurs.

It is thus up to the compiler to decide whether the copy constructor is called on return in a case like this.

Comment: Only on return statements.  However, no default bit copy occurs in either case.  The two choices are (a) a deep copy and (b) no copy at all.  How is (b), no copy at all, possible?  Because the called function *originally* uses the caller's memory to construct the object.  In case (b), the caller never has its own, local object at all.  If you are getting (c) an actual bit-copy, this is behavior I admit that I have never seen.

Comment: I was getting confused because when i made the copy constructor private i was getting compiler error. But i found the reason for that in the this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733448/why-copy-constructor-is-called-when-passing-temp-by-const-ref

Answer (score 10):

It creates a temporary object, which then gets copied to the return value.

But for efficiency, C++ allows calls to the copy constructor (or the move constructor in C++11) to be *elided*, so you should not rely on side-effects of copy constructors occurring.

See [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [Want Speed? Pass By Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: But what if i dont want shallow copy to happen, like if there is some pointer initialization and i want defined copy constructor to be called?

Comment: @rocky: The RVO means that instead of copying, the object essentially gets constructed in the memory space of the callee variable (`testO3` in your case).  Why would you *need* to have the copy constructor called?

Answer (score 0):

I tell you what happening when `return` a constructor, lets make a good example for you. I refer a class named `Counter` returning in two ways :

**return by temporary object :**

```
// method 1
class Counter
{
private :
    int count;
public :
    Counter() : count(0) {}
    int get_count(void);
    Counter operator++(int);
};

int Counter::get_count()
{
    return count;
}

Counter Counter::operator++(int)
{
    count++;
    // create a temp object and assigning count value, then return.
    Counter temp;
    temp.count = count;
    return temp;
}
```

**return by nameless temporary object:**

```
// method 2
class Counter
{
private :
    int count;
public :
    Counter() : count(0) {}
    Counter(int c) : count(c) {}
    int get_count(void);
    Counter operator++(int);
};

int Counter::get_count()
{
    return count;
}

Counter Counter::operator++(int)
{
    count++;
    // call 'Counter(int c)' constructor
    return Counter(count);
}
```

**main :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Counter c1, c2;
    c1++;
    c1++;
    c2 = c1++;
    cout << "c1=" << c1.get_count() << endl;
    cout << "c2=" << c2.get_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of both methods are identical, the `return Counter(count);` statement in second `class` does what all three statements did in the first. this statement creates an object of type `Counter`, this object has no name; it wont be around long enough to need one. this unnamed object is initialized to the value provided by the argument `count`, once the unnamed object is initialized to the value of `count`, it can then be returned.

The effect of the first `class` are the same as the second `class` :

Output :

```
c1= 3
c2= 3
```

notice, in `c2 = c1++;` statement `c1` increased then assigned to `c2`.