# Relevance of const return type in NRVO cases

Tags: c++

This is a follow up question from [Calling constructor in return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941730/calling-constructor-in-return-statement).

This a operator overload fun in a class.

```
const Integer operator+(const Integer& IntObject)
{
    cout << "Data : " << this->data << endl;
    return Integer(this->data + IntObject.data); 
}
```

What is the relevance of const in the return type for such functions?

```
int main()
{
    Integer A(1); //Create 2 object of class Integer

    Integer B(2);

    const Integer C = A + B;  //This will work

    Integer D = A + B;        //This will also work

    fun(A + B);               //Will work
}

void fun(Integer F) {}
```

This is a case temporaries are not created during return step due to NRVO. The object to be returned is directly constructed on the callee's address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relevance in your code snippet, because you are making a **copy** of the returned value.

In general, it is difficult to find good reasons to return a `const` value. I can only see it having an effect in this type of expression, attempting to call a non-const method on a `const` temporary:

```
(someObject.someMethodReturningConstValue()).someNonConstMethod(); // error, calls non const method on const temporary
```

so you should only use it if you want to disallow calling non-const methods on temporaries. On the other hand, it kills move-semantics in C++11 so is discouraged.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a better example:

```
struct Foo
{
    void gizmo();
    Foo const operator+(Foo const & rhs);
};
```

Now if you have a `Foo x; Foo y;`, then you *cannot* say:

```
(x + y).gizmo();  // error!
```

The constant return value means you cannot use it for non-constant operations. For primitive types this is not quite so relevant, because there aren't many non-constant operations you can perform on temporary objects, because lots of "interesting" operations (like prefix-`++`) aren't allowed on temporaries.

That said, with C++11 one should really try and adopt the new idiom of never returning constant values, since non-constant values are now amenable to move optimisations.

Comment: From all the answers i get that const return type was/is used in such cases from preventing modifying action on temporaries(if any) created during 'return'.  And according to C++11 i should avoid using const return type in such cases ?

Comment: @rocky if you want to prevent calling non-const on temporaries you don't really have a choice, it just means that you won't benefit from move semantics if and when applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Some people used to suggest doing that, to prevent writing nonsense like `A + B = C`. However, in C++11 it can prevent some optimisations since it makes the return value unmovable. Therefore, you shouldn't do it.

In this case, it also prevents you from writing perfectly valid code like `D = A + B + C`, but that's just because the author forgot to declare the operator `const`.